# How to display the parent data-tab value if child radio button is checked without change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have four radio buttons. I am getting the radio button value from the database and according to the value radio button will check. Now the first radio button is checked. I need `data-tab` value of the radio button which is selected. So that I can show the div. So I tried below code but it displays `undefined`. I have to add the class `current` to the Id value.

Onload I am getting the radio button value. Now how do I get the `data-tab` value without change?

For example, the first radio button is `a`. so `data-tab` value is `tab-1`. So I need `tab-1` to show in the div.
Would you help me out on this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var ab=$("input[name='payment_details']:checked").val()

  if (ab) {
    alert(ab);
    var tab_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-tab');;
    alert(tab_id);
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="tabs payment_details_tab">
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="a" value="a" checked="">
    <label class="radio_text" for="a"> a</label>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="b" value="b">
    <label class="radio_text" for="b">b</label>

  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="c" value="c">
    <label class="radio_text" for="c">c</label>

  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="d" value="d">
    <label class="radio_text" for="d"> d</label>

  </li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), you are using is not referencing the element you are thinking. It is referencing the `HTMLDocument`.

Instead of using [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the selector use the element:

```
$($("input[name='payment_details']:checked")).parent().attr('data-tab');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var ab=$("input[name='payment_details']:checked").val()

  if (ab) {
    alert(ab);
    var tab_id = $($("input[name='payment_details']:checked")).parent().attr('data-tab');
    alert(tab_id);
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    
    console.log(this.constructor.name); //HTMLDocument
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="tabs payment_details_tab">
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="a" value="a" checked="">
    <label class="radio_text" for="a"> a</label>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="b" value="b">
    <label class="radio_text" for="b">b</label>

  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="c" value="c">
    <label class="radio_text" for="c">c</label>

  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="d" value="d">
    <label class="radio_text" for="d"> d</label>

  </li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Though you can use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside `.each()` like the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("input[name='payment_details']:checked").each(function(){
    var ab=$(this).val();
    if (ab) {
      console.log(ab);
      var tab_id = $(this).parent().attr('data-tab');
      console.log(tab_id);
      $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');

      console.log(this); //currently checked radio element
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="tabs payment_details_tab">
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="a" value="a" checked="">
    <label class="radio_text" for="a"> a</label>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="b" value="b">
    <label class="radio_text" for="b">b</label>

  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="c" value="c">
    <label class="radio_text" for="c">c</label>

  </li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">
    <input type="radio" name="payment_details" id="d" value="d">
    <label class="radio_text" for="d"> d</label>

  </li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"></div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Give me some time to understand.

Comment: Yes, It's working, Perfectly,  Someone told me that It's not possible without chage event and you solved my issue  within 2 min. Thanks @Mamun, upvote from myside